# Retrieving equal numpy array after storing as string in db

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I have a list of numpy.float32 elements which I extract from a query image:

```
[0.013991388, 0.0070270086, 0.0012525863, 0.013302466, . . . etc
```

This is stored in an object and also within the database as a String. Then the object value is compared to the retrieved database value (after converting it from a String of course).

And yet, however similar they seem, I can't seem to get them equal again. For example I am running the chi2 distance algorithm to compute the distance and expect to be able to return 0.0 for the same image.

**My conversion code:**

```
# converts string to numpy array (matrix). MUST CAST to float32 otherwise pythons float64 by default, this will not
# match with our query array even if they are the same image!!!
def toMatrix(text):
    text = text.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    floats = [np.float32(x) for x in text.split(',')]

    return floats
```

After converting the string back to a list of floats with the above I compare it with the list stored in the object by pasting one after the other into a PyCharm text file. Inspecting the local history shows that no changes have occurred and visually the two arrays are identical.

So it's a type problem I think to myself. I print out the types of both lists first element e.g. `type(listA[0]), type(listB[0])` and both are numpy.float32.

So I use more general comparisons:

```
np.array_equal(listA, listB) # returns False
np.allclose(listA, listB)    # returns True
```

Trying to identify what isn't equal:

```
d = {}
count = 1
    for item in listA:
        if item not in listB:
            d[count] = type(item)
        count += 1
```

I get the peculiar result: `{124: <class 'numpy.float32'>}`

which is a single item within the two arrays???

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on exactly and how I can get the arrays equal?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string representation of your numbers numbers have 8 significant digits; [this is not enough to uniquely specify the binary representation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1251) of a `float32`.

- You should never assume that `float(string(number))==number` for floating point numbers. There are enough vagrancies in making the string representation of a floating point number that this is bound to fail if tried enough times.
- You should only test equality between floating point number if you really mean that you require the two numbers to be bit-wise equal (which in general is cannot be preserved when you create the string representation).  More often than not, what you want the "equal within tolerance" criterion that `numpy.allclose` uses.

If your situation allows it, you should consider saving the data arrays in binary format.  This will preserve the bit representation of the numbers across save/load (in case you really care about bitwise equality), and as an added benefit, this requires less storage space.

You are running into a floating point precision issue: the string representation is not the same as the binary representation.  Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import random
a=random.random()
np.float32( str(a)) == a
```

I got `False` on my first try (`print a => 0.893117245932`), maybe you won't, but there are floating point numbers where `float(string(number))` is not that number.

If you need to save them as strings, you should use [`numpy.tostring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) -- this will make a binary string from the values in the the array, such that `numpy.fromstring(numpy.tostring(array), dtype=numpy.float32) == array` (assuming `array.dtype==numpy.float32`).

If you don't care about the precision, then testing for approximate equality with a tolerance, as is used in `allclose`, might make sense.

Comment: I tried `numpy.array(list).tostring()` before storing it in my sqlite db and Django throws an error **'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 4:** Solutions to get around this by using latin-1 I assume aren't relevant for me using a sqlite db

Comment: @LukeVincent  you might consider changing the DB scheme to allow this field to be a binary blob.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably all of the items in listA are of type `numpy.float32`, so this code:

```
d[type(item)] = item
```

will assign to the same dictionary element over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to parse the string which is error prone and cumbersome. I would rather rely on something like json string to save the data, so you could convert and load the data without(or at least save most time) parsing it.

You could either create a `TextField` and save/load your array to it, or there might be something like [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) that somebody already created.

Comment: I didn't think a huge list of floats would be eligible as a json string as I've only ever used json for storing associative arrays. Trying it in Django I get the error: **TypeError: 0.013991388 is not JSON serializable**

Comment: You can only serialize strings and numbers to json, not objects. If your numbers are numpy specific types, you need to convert them to floats. Check what's allowed in json at http://www.json.org/.